# Is Minikube ony for developing or can it be used in Production as well

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to familiarise myself with kubernetes, and want to run a k8s stack on some low spec hw (think raspberry pi).

I found what [appears to be a great guide to set up kubernetes un Ubuntu](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-22-04/) but I ran into issues, causing me to reinstall the OS several times to ensure that I had not made a fundamental mistake which was poisoning my attempt.

Getting fed up with waiting for the basics, [I tried to set it up in a vagrant environment](https://github.com/JoSSte/k8s-playground),  which does allow me to skip some of the time-consuming and tedious steps regarding reinstalls, but still seems like a fragile process. Looking at udemy and youtube, as well as getting started articles, a lot of focus appears to be in minikube... as I read it, that is essentially a vm with a ready to go kubernetes set up already.

My question is: is the overhead using minikube small enough to use on servers with minimal resources? Or is it only usable for testing and demonstration? Since I have issues getting a working cluster, I can't test and verify it myself...

Comment: How is this related to programming? --- For resource-limited environments, I suggest taking a look at [`k3s.io`](https://k3s.io/).

Comment: Hoe is it not? Alternatively would be serverfault which would not be a match

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a catch-all. Just because it is not on-topic on [sf] does not mean it is on-topic here. All question must be related to programming.

Comment: so ensuring that what you code can run is not programming related? ensuring your stack works is not programming related? I actually read two meta posts regarding the exact question of whether this would be on topic. I do agree that it is more devops than pure dev, but not unrelated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on devops.stackexchange.com - i cannot delete it since it has 1 answer already

Answer (score 2):

From minikube [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/): `minikube is local Kubernetes, focusing on making it easy to learn and develop for Kubernetes`

If you want to learn more about Kubernetes, I suggest reading and implementing [this](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) repository.

In the end, if you want to use Kubernetes in production, please forget `minikube` and run Kubernetes.